# Mean and variance of a normally distributed random number created from the average of a set of uniformly distributed random numbers

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, uniform-distribution

An old-fashioned way of generating normally distributed random numbers entailed setting each normally distributed random number equal to the average of a set of uniformly distributed random numbers, rescaled and shifted by a constant.  Let x be a uniformly distributed random variable, i.e. p(x) = 0 if x < 0 and x ≥1; p(x) = 1 if 0 ≤ x <1.

How would I compute the mean and variance of the variable x?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29

Comment: So if a set of uniform variables is a to b, a set of uniform variables from a+x to b-x has the same mean and variance as the set of uniform variables from a to b?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "a set of uniform variables is a to b" nor what distinction you are making between a mean or variance of a random variable and the mean or variance of a "set of [random] variables."  Do you perhaps intend a set of *observations* of a single random variable?  Another possible confusion is the use of "x" as a random variable in the question and--apparently--as a parameter in the comment.  Is there any connection between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X \sim {\rm Uniform}(0,1)$, then

$E[X] = \int_0^1 x \, dx = \frac12 x^2 |_0^1 = \frac12$

$E[X^2] = \int_0^1 x^2 \, dx = \frac13 x^3 |_0^1 = \frac13$

$V[X] = E[X^2] - \{ E[X] \}^2 = \frac13 - \frac14 = \frac1{12}$

I hope I don't have to demonstrate $E[aX+b]$ and $V[aX+b]$ for you.

FYI, there are much better ways to generate normal variates that do not require inversion of the normal CDF, such as [the polar method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).